# Como hacer múltiples sumas en una columna de misma tabla? sql - c#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, windows-forms

Tengo el siguiente problema: Tengo una tabla en `SQL Server` donde tengo la información de alumnos con el precio mensual de membresía en la biblioteca. Lo que necesito es sumar total precio en una columna `Total` por el nombre de la persona siempre que agrego nuevos datos. Los intentos con usar `List<>` no me han funcionado.

Esta es, por ejemplo, la tabla y los datos las que quiero guardar en base de datos:

```
Nombre  |  Ano | Mes |Precio|Total    
Raul    | 2018 |  1  |3.20  |3.20   
Diego   | 2018 |  1  |3.20  |3.20    
Maria   | 2018 |  1  |3.10  |3.10     
Maria   | 2018 |  2  |3.10  |6.20    
Raul    | 2018 |  2  |3.10  |6.30
```

Esta es mi clase `Registro`:

```
Class Registro
{
    public int Nombre { get; set; }
    public int Ano { get; set; }
    public decimal Precio { get; set; }   
    public decimal Total {get; set; }
}
```

Así le asigno creo y asignó valores en un formulario de mi programa:

```
Registro rg = new Registro();
rg.Nombre = txtNombre.Text;
rg.Ano = Convert.ToInt32(txtAno.Text);
rg.Mes = Convert.ToInt32(txtMes.Text);
rg.Precio = Convert.ToDecimal(txtPrecio.Text);
```

Y así creo el comando SQL programáticamente para ejecutar un procedimiento almacenado que ejecutará una consulta:

```
  SqlCommand cmd;

  string insert = "insert into Alum(Nombre,Ano,Mes,Precio,Total) 
     values(@nom,@ano,@mes,@precio,@total)";
```

Y esta es una consulta ejemplo que hago a aquella tabla:

```
SELECT Nombre, Ano, sum(Precio) as Total
FROM Alum where Nombre = '" + txtNombre.Text + "' and Ano = '" + txtAno.Text + "'" + " GROUP BY Nombre, Ano ORDER BY Nombre COMMIT";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
```

Esta es la parte del código donde creo mi lista y la lleno con objetos:

```
List<Registro> registros = new List<Registro>()
                           {                          
                                new Registro()
                                {
                                    Total=Convert.ToDecimal(rg.total)
                                }
                           };       

decimal sumaTotales = registros.Sum(x => x.Total);
```

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]! Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y así ganar tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/84/informed). Lee [ask] y [¿sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) para aprender a realizar una buena pregunta. En tu caso, no esta muy claro cual es el problema.Necesitamos ver el código que estás probando y que error tienes.

Comment: No tengo ningun error pero no me hace nada en la base de datos. Siempre cuando inserto datos quiero que me sume la columna Precio en columna Total determinada por el Nombre. Mi espanol  esta mal pero estoy intendanto explicar lo mejor que puedo.

Comment: Qué gestor de base de datos estás usando? MySQL? MariaDB? SQL Server?

Comment: Estoy usando SQL Server

Comment: El problema, es que la columna total no deberia estar en la misma tabla. Habria que ver bien las reglas de negocios, pero no creo que eso este bien. En todo caso, las tablas de totales van separada.

Answer (score 2):

### Suma por Base de Datos

Para sumar los valores de la columna `Total` de tu tabla te recomiendo dejarle  esa tarea a tu gestor de base de datos (SQL Server, MySQL, etc.) al momento de hacer la consulta. Suponiendo que los valores de la columna sean numéricos, podrías llamar en la consulta SQL alguna función matemática que sume los valores de una columna.

**Por ejemplo:**

Si estás usando **SQL Server**, la función sería `SUM()`. Así podrías consultar el valor de la suma de los valores de la columna `Total`:

```
SELECT SUM(Total) as Total
FROM Alum
WHERE ...
```

Aquí te dejo la página del sitio de Microsoft MSDN que habla de esta función:

[SUM (Transact-SQL)](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/sum-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

### Suma programática

**Método `Sum()`:**

Si lo que necesitas es que el programa que estás desarrollando sea el que realice la suma de los valores del atributo `Total` de cada registro en una lista de registros, puedes hacer uso del método `Sum()` de la clase `Enumerable` para sumar todos los valores. Al ser las listas un tipo `Enumerable`, ya incluye este método.

**Por ejemplo:**

```
// Recuerda que lo ideal es que ya tenga elementos la lista.
List<Registros> listaRegistros = ...;
// En esta línea utilizamos el método para sumar los valores del atributo 'Total'.
decimal sumaTotales = listaRegistros.Sum(x => x.Total);
```

Aquí te dejo la página del sitio de Microsoft MSDN que habla de esta función:

[Método Enumerable.Sum(IEnumerable, Func)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/bb534734(v=vs.110).aspx)

**Haciendo uso de `foreach`:**

Ó podrías hacer la suma haciendo uso del ciclo `foreach`.

**Por ejemplo:**

```
// Recuerda que lo ideal es que ya tenga elementos la lista.
List<Registros> listaRegistros = ...;
decimal suma = 0M;

foreach (Registro x in listaRegistros)
{
    suma += x.Total;
}

// Resultado: la variable 'suma' contendrá el valor de la suma de los totales de los registros en la lista.
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por respuesta..Intentare resolver la problema que tengo

Comment: Con mucho gusto! Si soluciona tu problema e inquietud, podrías aprobar mi respuesta. c:

Comment: En esta manera he intentado pero sin exito                  
 List<registro> registros = new List<registro>() {
            new registro(){Precio=Convert.ToDecimal(cl.Precio)},
            new registro(){Total=Convert.ToDecimal(cl.Total)}
        };
            // En esta línea utilizamos el método para sumar los valores del atributo 'Total'.
            Decimal sumaTotales = Registros.Sum(x => x.Total);

Comment: No ha funcionado el método `Sum()`? Ya intentaste hacer uso del ciclo `foreach`? No te aparece el método `Sum()`?

Comment: He probado con los dos, pero nada...no se que hacer?

Comment: Intenta cambiando `Decimal` por `decimal`.

Comment: He intentado y no paso nada..

Comment: Al momento de aplicar el método en el comentario anterior, qué resultado te arroja? Tienes que tener en cuenta que estás creando nuevos registros, al hacerlo solo le asignas valor al total de uno de ellos. Al ser así, lo normal es que te arroje el método el valor de únicamente el total de ese objeto.

Comment: Tengo resultado que suma pero cuando reinicio app empieza sumar desde 0 y no me hase ningun error. Seguro que estoy aciendo cosa mal! Ariba he editado el codigo..Tambien necesito suma total determinada por los nombres.